# Text Field and List Views

Tags: android, android-edittext

Can I have a text field in an `Activity` other than your main `Activity`. I have a list that on click uses an activity which is the same for everyone.  However, I want the text fields to change based on which thing you click on the list. For example, if you click 'gym' in the list, I want the name text field to say 'Gym'.  How do you do this? Are variables in Main Activity public to other activities?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intents can be used to send data from one activity to another as shown below

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("MY_VAL","value");
startActivity(intent);
```

and it can be retrived at Activity2.class as shown below (write this code in oncreate on your second activity).

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("MY_VAL");
}
```